# lxml can't parse <table>?

Tags: python, parsing, lxml, web-crawler

I want to parse tables in html, but i found lxml can't parse it? what's wrong?

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import urllib
import lxml.etree
keyword = 'lxml+tutorial'

url = 'http://www.baidu.com/s?wd='
if __name__ == '__main__':
    page = 0

    link = url + keyword + '&pn=' + str(page)

    f = urllib.urlopen(link)
    content = f.read()
    f.close()

    tree = lxml.etree.HTML(content)

    query_link = '//table'

    info_link = tree.xpath(query_link)

    print info_link
```

the print result is just []...

Comment: This dosen't really answer the question for lxml but you may want to look at Beautiful Soup if you are having trouble parsing web pages: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Answer (score 3):

lxml's [documentation says](http://lxml.de/parsing.html), "The support for parsing broken HTML depends entirely on libxml2's recovery algorithm. It is not the fault of lxml if you find documents that are so heavily broken that the parser cannot handle them. There is also no guarantee that the resulting tree will contain all data from the original document. The parser may have to drop seriously broken parts when struggling to keep parsing."

And sure enough, the HTML returned by Baidu is invalid: the W3C [validator reports](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.baidu.com/s%3Fwd%3Dfoo%26pn%3D0&charset=(detect+automatically)&doctype=Inline&group=0) "173 Errors, 7 warnings". I don't know (and haven't investigated) whether these particular errors have caused your trouble with lxml, because I think that your strategy of using lxml to parse HTML found "in the wild" (which is nearly always invalid) is doomed.

For parsing invalid HTML, you need a parser that implements the ([surprisingly bizarre!](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/syntax.html#an-introduction-to-error-handling-and-strange-cases-in-the-parser)) HTML error recovery algorithm. So I recommend swapping lxml for [html5lib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html5lib), which handles Baidu's invalid HTML with no problems:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> from html5lib import html5parser, treebuilders
>>> p = html5parser.HTMLParser(tree = treebuilders.getTreeBuilder('dom'))
>>> dom = p.parse(urllib.urlopen('http://www.baidu.com/s?wd=foo').read())
>>> len(dom.getElementsByTagName('table'))
12
```

Comment: As I remember, lxml has hooks for BeautifulSoup and html5lib so it's necessary to discard it entirely. (I've yet to need them so I forgot)

Answer (score 2):

I see several places that code could be improved but, for your question, here are my suggestions:

1. Use `lxml.html.parse(link)` rather than `lxml.etree.HTML(content)` so all the "just works" automatics can kick in. (eg. Handling character coding declarations in headers properly)
2. Try using `tree.findall(".//table")` rather than `tree.xpath("//table")`. I'm not sure whether it'll make a difference, but I just used that syntax in a project of my own a few hours ago without issue and, as a bonus, it's compatible with non-LXML ElementTree APIs.

The other major thing I'd suggest would be using Python's built-in functions for building URLs so you can be sure the URL you're building is valid and properly escaped in all circumstances.

If LXML can't find a table and the browser shows a table to exist, I can only imagine it's one of these three problems:

1. Bad request. LXML gets a page without a table in it. (eg. error 404 or 500)
2. Bad parsing. Something about the page confused `lxml.etree.HTML` when called directly.
3. Javascript needed. Maybe the table is generated client-side.

Comment: Strange. I'm not sure where to go from there then. I'd have to start doing some testing and I'm already winding down for bed.